# Show an individual part of a string as output

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JavaScript code. I want to get only the value inside `li` tags using `JavaScript`. How can I do it?

**JavaScript**

```
    var s="<div><li>First LI</li><li>Second LI</li></div>";
```

I want to show `First li` and `Second li` as output. Thank you.

Comment: You are saying you need to do this using Javascript then why 'jquery' tag in question?

Comment: BTW li tags are usually found inside an ol or ul tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of jQuery it is rather easy:

```
var str = '<div><li>First LI</li><li>Second LI</li></div>',
    first  = $('li:eq(0)', str).text(),  // "First LI"
    second = $('li:eq(1)', str).text();  // "Second LI"

console.log(first, second);
```

Comment: @bd_user1 Should work: http://jsfiddle.net/224nn/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** to get the text content of your `li` elements:

```
var text = $(s).find('li').text();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uXWX5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use following javascript, get element by tag name and iterate over the values like below

```
var liArray = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i=0; i < liArray.length ;i++)
{
  var liValue = liArray[i].innerHTML;
  alert(liValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will output: 'First LI Second LI', the contents of both lis separated by a whitespace.

If you need it as array, just omit the join at the end.

```
var lisContent = $.map(
    $('li', "<div><li>First LI</li><li>Second LI</li></div>"), 
    function(element) {
        return $(element).text();
    }
).join(' ');

console.log(lisContent);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gG3k/

Answer (score 0):

check here, this may help you

```
 <div><li>First LI</li><li>Second LI</li></div>
```

```
 $('.btn').click(function(){
 alert($('div li').text());
 });

 http://jsfiddle.net/Sathisa/78ktD/
```